# What's the meaning of "education community" in the context?

Tags: meaning, interpretation

a policy that has been adopted by the entire **education community.**

Is this implies??:- a group of people who are involved in the act or process of imparting knowledge, esp at a school, college, or university.

Comment: Given it's the ***entire*** education community, I think "**a** group of people who are involved in [education]" is an odd way to refer to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *entire* education community is *everyone* involved in delivering education in the whole country, or perhaps the world.  All teachers, teaching assistants, university professors, teacher trainers, and so on.

Comment: Yes,Can I understand it the way I interpreted??

Comment: Is there any context?  If, for example you were talking about your town, the you might compare the education community (in the town) with the medical community (in the town).  But you would not use it about the people who are involved in education *at a school* since everyone who works at a school is part of the eduction community in one way or another.

Comment: Yes, but i also mentioned **"the act or process of imparting knowledge"**

Comment: I'm  not sure what you're asking.  That looks like a dictionary definition of "education", although it is possibly too narrow (education isn't just about knowledge, but more generally about child, (and adult) development.)