# How can I interpretate the term"scientific community" in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

The project has attracted considerable criticism from the **scientific community**.

Community mean as per Cambridge -the people living in one particular area or people who are considered as a unit because of their common interests, social group, or nationalit.

Scientific mean as per Cambridge -  relating to science, or using the organized methods of science.

How I can interprete the sentence using above definitions??

Comment: All the scientists in the world, or a significant part of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of "education community" in the context?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340482/whats-the-meaning-of-education-community-in-the-context) Which was your question anyway - why do you need to ask the same thing about the ***scientific** community*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers but that definition do not fit here.So I asked. I can't say group of people who are whose interest is related to science.

Comment: why not? more accurately, whose interest is related to *conducting* science as opposed to *hearing about* science, but the same could be said about the "education community."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very broad sense of "the X community" to mean "all that people that are X", such as "the queer community" or "the Islamic community".

In this case, it is basically synonymous with "scientists".

Comment: Well, scientists in that field - astrophysics rarely criticise biologists.

Comment: It implies a bit more than just all the scientists independently: the scientific community implies a collective attitude or opinion, and could include bodies that represent or act for groups of scientists such as university faculties, professional societies, journals.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "criticism from the scientific community" means that some scientists have stated criticism. It's not very specific because it could be just a few scientists or most of them.